# Couldn't find executable named error Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, executable

I am trying to fly the ardrone parrot 2.0 using tum_ardrone ptam module. It is a rospackage, so I had to make it using

```
       rosmake tum_ardrone
```

The above compiled with 0 failures. however, when I do the following commad

```
       rosrun tum_ardrone drone_stateestimation
```

I get the following error

```
      [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named drone_stateestimation below

      /home/bojan/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone
```

I tried to google and get a solid pipelined solution to check for the reason for this error and solve it, but I did not get it. Am new to ubuntu, thus your help is much appreicated. This error doesn't seem to be package specific since the same package works fine in another laptop I tested. Am runnign Ubuntu in vmWare. Does that make any difference?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is an ubuntu issue at all... I think you need to reinstall [ardrone](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone/drone_stateestimation). Regardless "ros != ubuntu".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : I tried, but its still not working. Every other executable is working. For eg : drone_gui etc. Except this one. Any other specific reason for this?

Comment: Does `find /home/bojan/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone -name "drone_stateestimation"` actually find an executable?

Comment: actually, the executable is not found in the bin folder. it is not created. but in cmake it is there. target executable and is linked with the libraries. wat can be the issue then @ElliottFrisch

Comment: You should probably post that as a question on stackoverflow. It isn't an Ubuntu package, your appear to be having an issue with building your software. You may be able to follow [these](https://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/AR_drone_2/Software_installation) instructions, but I have never worked with your "AR_drone".